# Multiple file Attachment and sending mail using Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

Here i like to explain my problem clearly

> Am able to upload multiple file, but the problem am not getting the
>   attached files in my mail, only one attachment alone am receiving, in
>   server all files getting saved

```
$model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'attachment');
$files = '';

if ( $model->attachment )
{
    foreach ($model->attachment as $file) 
    {
        $file->saveAs('emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension);
        $files = 'emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension;
        $model->attachment = $files;
    }

}
if( $model->attachment )
{
    $value = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom([ Yii::$app->user->identity->email => 'Sample Mail'])
    ->setTo($model->email)
    ->setSubject($model->subject)
    ->setHtmlBody($model->content)
    ->attach($model->attachment)
    ->send();
}
```

Am upload multiple files but while sending mail, only one attachment itself receiveing. 
How can i sort out this?

Comment: What is the `attach()` method expecting? An array with filenames of files you want to attach to the mail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html#file-attachment), the `attach()` method expects the filename (string) as parameter. To fix your code:

```
$model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'attachment');

if($model->attachment) {
    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom([ Yii::$app->user->identity->email => 'Sample Mail'])
    ->setTo($model->email)
    ->setSubject($model->subject)
    ->setHtmlBody($model->content);

    foreach ($model->attachment as $file) {
        $filename = 'emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension; # i'd suggest adding an absolute path here, not a relative.
        $file->saveAs($filename);
        $message->attach($filename);
    }

    $message->send();
}
```

Comment: Haha, you're kidding right? Couldn't you figure out that I just missed a `;` on the `setHtmlBody()` line?

Comment: no need to add Swift_Attachment, it is in built with attach()

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer for everyone who gets here in the future.

Comment: @Bjorn just one file was uploaded ?! I updated my code to be like your code

Answer (score 0):

In your code you assign only the last. If you want all files you should concatened them in a composed one  or in a way compatible with you email composition.

try with something like this

```
$model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'attachment');
    if ($model->attachment) {

      $value = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom([Yii::$app->user->identity->email => 'Sample Mail'])
        ->setTo($model->email)
        ->setSubject($model->subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($model->content);

      foreach ($model->attachment as $file) {
        $name = 'emailattachments/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
        $file->saveAs($name);
        $value->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($name));
      }

      $value->send();
    }
```

Comment: Am getting this error **fopen(emailattachments/Invoice_1500 (1).pdf; emailattachments/Invoice_1500 (2).pdf; ): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Comment: this mean the pathname for the attachment files  is not correct.

Comment: am getting this error **finfo_file(C:\wamp\tmp\php50C7.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Comment: `;` mistake in `$value->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($name));`

Comment: How nice of you to [practically steal my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31491947/revisions).